# Basic bash printing question

Tags: bash, scripts

I know this question is basic knowing how to write script, but I didn't learn that yet:

I have a program that takes, as an input, a list like:
`str_1,str_2, etc`.
The string is always the same, but the numbers go from 1 to 1,000. Obviously, it is not possible to write this manually, so I want to generate the argument `str_1,str_2, etc` automatically and then copy it to the shell (or, if there is a better way to do, please let me know).

How can I generate this list?

Comment: It depends on the application, do you call it via the shell, with the string as argument? In principal, in python this would be a peace of cake.

Comment: yes this is what I do. which library would you use in python to do this?

Comment: to make sure: the command is: application_name string?

Comment: that is correct: python programName arguments (the first argument being the string)

Comment: excuse me, having a little difficulties pasting code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os

def create_list(string_input):
    number = 0
    string_list = []
    while number <= 1000:
        number = number+1
        string_list.append(string_input+str(number))
    return(string_list)

command_list = create_list(string_input = "test")
for item in command_list:
    os.system("firefox -new-tab "+item)
```

This would run firefox 1000 times, opening new tabs with "test1, test2" as url (don't try :))

change "string_input" to your string, "firefox -new-tab" to your application.

edit: I must have had a weak moment, can be much shorter in python as well of course:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

command_list = [
    "firefox -new-tab "+"test"+str(number) for number in range(0,1001)
    ]
for command in command_list:
    subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: btw, I the script is in python3

Comment: Python is probably overkill for this task. Also, the `os.system` call is superseded by `subprocess.call()`. Also, commands should be specified in a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
# array=( str_1 str_2 str_3 ... str_1000 )
array=( str_{1..1000} )          

# prints the content of the array as a single string with comma between elements. 
# str_1,str_2,str_3,...,str_1000   
( IFS=,; printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"; )
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 for more on using arrays in bash.

Comment: That looks nice! I will look into that, thanks for the link!

Comment: ./mystring.bash $(tt=$(echo str_{1..1000}) ; echo ${tt// /,})

Answer (score 1):

This will work nicely in Bash only:

```
array=( str_{1..1000} )
joined_array="$(printf '%s,' "${array[@]}")"
echo "${joined_array%,}"
```

The last `echo` line is to omit the trailing comma.

First line of the commands is from [geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/430248/176889).

Answer (score 0):

There are, as always, plenty of solutions.

Personally, for such a simple thing as this, neither do I write a whole Python script, nor do I declare arrays in bash or change the internal field separator.

Instead I just write something like this, right from the command line, in one line:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do printf str_$i,; done
```

This will output a string `str_1,str_2,...,str_1000,`. Depending on the level of automation you need, if you would like to strip the trailing `,` then one of an estimated gajillion possibilities is to use `sed`:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do printf str_$i,; done | sed 's/,$//;'
```

giving you `str_1,str_2,...,str_1000`.

**Update:**

It just came to me that since you only want to do a print, you can even do without an explicit loop. Short & crisp:

```
echo str_{1..1000} | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

The latter command also gives you `str_1,str_2,...,str_1000`.

Explanation: The `echo str_{1..1000}` outputs `str_1 str_2 ... str_1000`. The `sed 's/ /,/g'` replaces all whitespaces by commas.